# Prime number algorithm not working

Tags: java, loops, primes

```
package coding;
public class Prob7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long flag=0;
    long counter=0;
    long prime;
    for(prime=2;;prime++){
        System.out.println(counter);
        flag=0;
        long check=2;
        while(check<=prime/2){
            if(prime%check==0){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0){
            if(counter==10001){
                System.out.println(prime);
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }

    }


  }

}
```

I want to find the 10001st prime number and I nested a while loop inside a for loop for finding if it is a prime number or not. I used flag to check outside the loop and break out of the while loop if necessary. But the console was not doing anything. So next line of the for loop, I put the `System.out.println(counter);`for checking what is happening. The counter prints out

```
0
1
2
2
```

and stops. I tried debugging but I couldn't figure out the problem. 
I have not set a condition for the for loop as I have a break statement which will break out of the loop if the counter of prime numbers reaches 10001.

PS: I know I can use isPrime(), but I just wanna practice these kinds of algorithms.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to debug simple programs with a straight forward bug this this one.  If you don't you will find it hard to debug much harder programs.

Comment: Once you start trying to debug multi-threaded applications, this can seem impossible at times.

Comment: BTW you only need to loop up to sqrt(n) and after skipping even numbers you only need to check odd ones i.e. `for (int check = 3, max = (int) Math.sqrt(prime); i < max; i+=2)`  This will be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

You don't increment `check` variable in the inner `while` loop. Modify to:

```
    while(check<=prime/2){
        if(prime%check==0){
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
        ++check;
    }
```

In general there are many ways how to improve the algorithm:

1. you can test 2 at the beginning and then just go over odd numbers (so `check += 2`)
2. You may compute sqrt(prime) at the beginning and then only loop until the square root (as (sqrt(x)+1)^2 will be always higher then prime already.
3. You could consider completely different algorithm, remembering the primes which were already successfully tested and while testing another prime test already found primes only as a divisor. This is similar to [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Ah! There you go brother. Thank you. So silly of me. By the way the algorithm I am using is taking loads of time(like 20s) to complete. is `isPrime()` more efficient?

Comment: @SiddharthVenu I suggest you prove to yourself that you can see this problem in a debugger (now you know what it is doing)

Comment: @SiddharthVenu : There are plenty of ways how to improve it. First you can test 2 at the beginning and then just go over odd numbers (so `check += 2). Second you may compute sqrt(prime) at the beginning and then only loop until the square root (as (sqrt(x)+1)^2 will be always higher then prime already. Third you could consider completely different algorithm, remembering the primes which were already tested and go through them only.

Comment: Consider promoting that comment to your answer, in particular your last point. Then I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You don't increment `check` in your `while` loop. For now, increase it by 2 each time (there's no point in scanning over the even numbers with the exception of 2). There are quicker ways still, but this will do for now.

Also, you only need to run to the square root of `prime`, not half way. That will speed things up a little.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I'll try it now. Thank you